# Access child object attributes in a dxDataGrid

Tags: knockout.js, devexpress, devextreme

I'm building an app (multi-channel) with a lot of data grids and there is this problem that I can't find a solution for it in `DevExtreme` tutorials and guides.
I implemented a `dxDataGrid` with the `knockout` approach, here is my entity:

```
(function() {
    Application1.playerViewModel = function(data) {
            this.id = ko.observable();
            this.firstname = ko.observable();
            this.lastname = ko.observable();
            this.fullname = ko.observable();
            this.date_of_birth = ko.observable();
            this.country = ko.observable();
            this.team = ko.observable();
            this.teamname = ko.observable();
            this.position = ko.observable();
            if(data)
                this.fromJS(data);
    };

    $.extend(Application1.playerViewModel.prototype, {
        toJS: function () {
            return {
                id: this.id(),
                firstname: this.firstname(),
                lastname: this.lastname(),
                date_of_birth: this.date_of_birth(),
                fullname: this.firstname()+" "+this.lastname,
                country: Application1.db.objectLink("countries", this.country() ? this.country().id(): undefined),
                team: Application1.db.objectLink("teams", this.team() ? this.team().id() : undefined),
                teamname: this.team().name(),
                position: Application1.db.objectLink("positions", this.position() ? this.position().id(): undefined),
            };
        },

        fromJS: function(data) {
            if(data) {
                this.id(data.id);
                this.firstname(data.firstname);
                this.lastname(data.lastname);
                this.fullname(data.firstname + " " + data.lastname);
                this.date_of_birth(data.date_of_birth);
                if(data.country)
                    this.country(new Application1.countryViewModel(data.country));
                if(data.team){
                    this.team(new Application1.teamViewModel(data.team));
                    this.teamname = data.team.name;
                }
                if(data.position)
                    this.position(new Application1.positionViewModel(data.position));
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Here is the `viewModel`:

```
Application1.players = function (params, viewInfo) {
    "use strict";

    var shouldReload = false,
        openCreateViewAsRoot = viewInfo.layoutController.name === "split",
        playersDataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
            store: Application1.db.players,
            map: function (item) {
                return new Application1.playerViewModel(item);
            }
        }),
        dataFieldList =  [
            { dataField: 'firstname', allowGrouping: false },
            { dataField: 'lastname', allowGrouping: false },
            { dataField: 'date_of_birth', sortIndex: 0, sortOrder: 'asc', allowGrouping: false },
            { dataField: 'country', visible: false },
            { dataField: 'team', allowGrouping: true },
            { dataField: 'position', allowGrouping: true },
            { dataField: 'fullname', visible: false, allowGrouping: false}
        ], columnChooser = { enabled: true }, allowColumnReordering = true, sorting = { mode: 'multiple' },
            groupPanel = { visible: true, emptyPanelText: 'Drag a column header here to group grid records' },
            pager = { visible: true },
            paging = { pageSize: 10 },
            editing = {
                editEnabled: true,
                editMode: 'row',
                insertEnabled: true,
                removeEnabled: true
            },
            filterRow = { visible: true },
            searchPanel = { visible: true },
            selection = { mode: 'none' } ;

    function handleplayersModification() {
        shouldReload = true;
    }

    function handleViewShown() {
        if (shouldReload) {
            shouldReload = false;
            dataSource.pageIndex(0);
            dataSource.load();
        }
    }

    function handleViewDisposing() {
        Application1.db.players.off("modified", handleplayersModification);
    }

    function refreshList() {
        dataSource.pageIndex(0);
        dataSource.load();
    }

    Application1.db.players.on("modified", handleplayersModification);

    return {
        refreshList: refreshList,
        viewShown: handleViewShown,
        viewDisposing: handleViewDisposing,
        openCreateViewAsRoot: openCreateViewAsRoot,
        players: playersDataSource,
        dataFieldList: dataFieldList,
        columnChooser: columnChooser,
        allowColumnReordering: allowColumnReordering,
        sorting: sorting,
        groupPanel: groupPanel,
        pager: pager,
        paging: paging,
        editing: editing,
        filterRow: filterRow,
        searchPanel: searchPanel,
        selection: selection
    };
};
```

The HTML:

```xml
 <div style="height:800px; margin: 0 auto"
         data-bind="dxDataGrid:{ dataSource:players, columns:dataFieldList, columnChooser:columnChooser, allowColumnReordering:allowColumnReordering, sorting:sorting, groupPanel:groupPanel, pager:pager, paging:paging, editing:editing, filterRow:filterRow, searchPanel:searchPanel, selection:selection }"></div>
```

And the result:
[image]

I tried putting `team.name` and `position.name` in the `dataFields` of the configuration object `dataFieldList` but it returns blank columns.

Comment: Thanks Tanner for your comment, but unfortunately team().name and team().name() doesn't work and both return this: http://bit.ly/1zPg0bj I think they return undefined in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you do not need to use a Knockout-driven view model in the dxDataGrid data source, because dxDataGrid provides CRUD support out of the box. So, nothing prevents you from building a flat object that exactly matches your columns schema, instead of using a generated view model.

Also, if you are using the ODataContext, it will not load navigation properties unless you explicitly specify this via the **extend** option. Read the [Associations](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/Data_Layer/Data_Source_Examples/#Data_Layer_Data_Source_Examples_OData_Associations) document for details.

Your data source definition might be as follows:

```
playersDataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
    store: Application1.db.players,
    map: function (item) {
        return {
            firstname: item.firstname,
            lastname: item.lastname,
            date_of_birth: item.date_of_birth,
            country: item.country.name,
            team: item.team.name,
            position.item.position.name,
            fullname: item.fullname
        };
    },
    expand: ['country', 'team', 'position']
}),
```

**Update**
My previous answer is not the best, because if you declare the data source this way, you will not edit country, team and position. To support editing, remove the **map** method from the data source and use [lookup](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/lookup/) columns. In this situation, you even do not need to expand navigation properties, because they will be expanded by lookups. Here is a short example:

```
playersDataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
    store: Application1.db.players
}),
columns:[{ 
    dataField: country, 
    lookup: { 
        dataSource: { store: Application1.db.countries }, 
        displayExpr: 'name',
        valueExpr: 'id'
    }
}]
```

Comment: Thank you Uranus, I followed your second solution and it got me close but it doesn't show the team name in each row, here's the result: http://bit.ly/1xnByFS and the columns object: http://pastebin.com/7DFXFyb8 (I removed the map attribute from the data source)

Comment: displayExpr and valueExpr options used to reference data source item fields. Has the team item corresponding fields (name and id)? If no, change the displayExpr and valueExpr options to reference existing fields.

Comment: Yes it's the same as position, a team has an id and name properties. Here's the team viewmodel: http://pastebin.com/iQwK1ckh

Comment: I can only assume that the player has a separate field for team id, and you need to set the dataField column option not to 'team' but to this field. If you add the **map** function to the data source, you can but the breakpoint into this function and see in the debugger which fields an item has.

Comment: Well, you are right. The player has a field team_id but when I put that field in the dataField column and put 'id' in the valueExpr field it doesn't work:

Comment: I also tried to put team_id in the column (dataField) and valueExpr (lookup) it shows the same team for all the players: http://pastebin.com/yKN4URhu

Comment: What if you remove the **map** function from the data source? At least, it is not required here because you are using the dxDataGrid.

Comment: If I remove the map function in the player data source it doesn't work at all.